# Laravel can't find service

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I managed to create custom validation rule following: http://www.sitepoint.com/data-validation-laravel-right-way-custom-validators/ 
My only problem is that in laravel 5 there is new file structure. It should be: 
`in <?php namespace App\Providers; ValidationExtensionServiceProvider.php`
`in <?php namespace App\Services; ValidatorExtended.php`
But laravel cant find my ValidatorExtended.php if its not in App\Providers. Error:

```
FatalErrorException in ValidationExtensionServiceProvider.php line 11: Class 'App\Providers\ValidatorExtended' not found
```

How do I tell laravel, to look in App\Services, not in App\Providers?

ValidatorExtended.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Validation\Validator as IlluminateValidator;

class ValidatorExtended extends IlluminateValidator {

    private $_custom_messages = array(
        ....
    );

    public function __construct( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages = array(), $customAttributes = array() ) 
    {
         parent::__construct( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);

         $this->_set_custom_stuff();
    } 

     ....



}
```

ValidationExtensionServiceProvider.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ValidationExtensionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

     public function register() {}

     public function boot() {
          $this->app->validator->resolver( function( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages = array(), $customAttributes = array() ) {
              return new ValidatorExtended( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes );
          }
     } 

}
```

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload` on your console at the root of your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace of your `ValidatorExtended` accessor:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ValidationExtensionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

     public function register() {}

     public function boot() {
          $this->app->validator->resolver( function( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages = array(), $customAttributes = array() ) {
              return new App\Services\ValidatorExtended( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes );
          }
     } 
}
```

or add a use statement at the top of your file:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Services\ValidatorExtended;

class ValidationExtensionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

     public function register() {}

     public function boot() {
          $this->app->validator->resolver( function( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages = array(), $customAttributes = array() ) {
              return new ValidatorExtended( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes );
          }
     } 
}
```

Comment: I actually tried use App\Services; before posting question, thought it will find use 'ValidatorExtended' by itself, actually haven't tried full path. Thank You.